# Blue screen after connecting to additional monitors when using external USB to run windows 10 on mac

Tags: windows-10, mac, external-hard-drive, external-display

I am using an external USB hard drive to run windows 10 on my mac. Everything works fine until I connect external displays. The system just crashed and it remains a blurry blue screen even I manually reboot it. Anyone have solution for this problem?

Thanks!

[The blue screen looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsCKl.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any information on what Bluescreen you are getting? You can also look in the memory dump if you enabled them.

Comment: @CentrixDE I just updated the post with the pic of blue screen. It does not have any information on it and it remains even I reboot the windows. 
I tried to reinstall the windows on my external hard drive and test it again. It works for a couple of minutes and then turned this blue screen again.